# Infer dimensionality of a graph based on the distances of between nodes

Tags: real-analysis, graph-theory

This problem just appeared into my mind and I don't know how to properly formulate it mathematicaly,or even if it makes sense. But I wonder if this already has some mathematical treatment or even a solution.
What I think is, supposed you have a graph and the associated weights for each edges. Is there an algorithm to know what is the minimum number of dimensions n in order to 'embed' this graph in an n-dimensional space such that the nodes are points and the weights correspond to the actual distances between these points?

Comment: If you want to google around, this is related to (but not exactly the same thing as): multidimensional scaling.  In multidimensional scaling you have a distance matrix--this would be the equivalent of a complete graph with non-negative (positive) edge weights.  When the process is applied, you select a dimension of the space in which to make the embedding and the algorithm determines points in that space which have the pairwise distances specified approximately the best that can be done in that dimension.  There's likely some research out there around the minimum dimension for exact solutions.

Comment: There's also a possibility that your graph cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$.  For example, suppose $w(a,b)=1$, $w(a,c)=1$, and $w(b,c)>2$ (weights of edges from a-b and a-c are both 1 and the weight of the edge from b-c is bigger than 2...).  In this case you cannot embed the graph at all since no matter where you put those points, and given any distance metric, the triangle inequality will not hold.

Comment: That is true, I was just realizing that. However I wonder if there is any mathematical space, probably non-euclidian where this could be allowed. That is, where you could define distances such that the triangle inequality does not need to hold

Comment: If the triangle inequality does not hold, then your function is not (by definition) a distance metric.  But maybe you don't really care about the weights being distances (in some metric)?